# Ошибка безопасности при использовании getUrl() в Firefox WebExtension

Tags: javascript, firefox, chrome-extension, firefox-extension

Пробую портировать раcширение из Хрома и получаю такую ошибку:

*Security Error: Content at "http://example.com" may not load or link to "moz-extension://04d69802-c26f-47ae-86f2-d54650455e5a/blocks/indicators/__icon/indicators__icon-tweet.png"*

```
(function () {
  'use strict';
  var PATHS = {
    TWITTER: chrome.extension.getURL("blocks/indicators/__icon/indicators__icon-tweet.png")
  };
})();
```

В *manifest.json* пути указаны в *web_accessible_resources*.

```
  "web_accessible_resources": [
    "blocks/indicators/__icon/*",
    "blocks/namespace/*",
    "blocks/vk-inner/*",
    "moz-extension://*"
  ],
```

Comment: судя по [документации](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/Add-ons/WebExtensions/manifest.json/web_accessible_resources), должно работать - что конкретно указано в manifest.json? какая версия Firefox? (лучше сразу тестировать в "dev edition")

Comment: @Nickolay, Firefox Developer Edition 47.0a2 (2016-04-13),

Подлинковал _[manifest.js](http://pastebin.com/5jXDDxYX)_

Answer (score 1):

Нужно прописывать полный путь к ресурсу в *web_accessible_resources.*

```
"web_accessible_resources": [
   "blocks/indicators/__icon/indicators__icon-tweet.png"
]
```